# XML Validation fails when validated against schema

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-namespaces

I generated the xml schema files (XSD) files for below xml using xsd.exe tool.
It gave me two schema files for the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd" version="3.2" serie="C" folio="371" fecha="2015-03-04T12:48:04" sello="abnLKgvWQ+pPBW1YSI/N941kf7eDOn8GBttp1/AJAdkQS6n60s37saV9ugTfOpYM4G+Q+4zr0jn0RQldamFyMDo/F3BfPg3R9yG8SD5A45i4Sh3CL/El2AHH/Zkyvft8b+BgFAMCoauvpi61BOCNK1EjEPcro0eZoy8ZRBfv+Xo=" formaDePago="PAGO EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION" noCertificado="00001000000301540335" certificado="MIIEXTCCA0WgAwIBAgIUMDAwMDEwMDAwMDAzMDE1NDAzMzUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwggGKMTgwNgYDVQQDDC9BLkMuIGRlbCBTZXJ2aWNpbyBkZSBBZG1pbmlzdHJhY2nDs24gVHJpYnV0YXJpYTEvMC0GA1UECgwmU2VydmljaW8gZGUgQWRtaW5pc3RyYWNpw7NuIFRyaWJ1dGFyaWExODA2BgNVBAsML0FkbWluaXN0cmFjacOzbiBkZSBTZWd1cmlkYWQgZGUgbGEgSW5mb3JtYWNpw7NuMR8wHQYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhBhY29kc0BzYXQuZ29iLm14MSYwJAYDVQQJDB1Bdi4gSGlkYWxnbyA3NywgQ29sLiBHdWVycmVybzEOMAwGA1UEEQwFMDYzMDAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAk1YMRkwFwYDVQQIDBBEaXN0cml0byBGZWRlcmFsMRQwEgYDVQQHDAtDdWF1aHTDqW1vYzEVMBMGA1UELRMMU0FUOTcwNzAxTk4zMTUwMwYJKoZIhvcNAQkCDCZSZXNwb25zYWJsZTogQ2xhdWRpYSBDb3ZhcnJ1YmlhcyBPY2hvYTAeFw0xMzEyMDQwMTI3NDlaFw0xNzEyMDQwMTI3NDlaMIGpMRswGQYDVQQDExJKT1JHRSBDT1JPTkEgRFVSQU4xGzAZBgNVBCkTEkpPUkdFIENPUk9OQSBEVVJBTjEbMBkGA1UEChMSSk9SR0UgQ09ST05BIERVUkFOMRYwFAYDVQQtEw1DT0RKNzAwMjE0NVEzMRswGQYDVQQFExJDT0RKNzAwMjE0SEJDUlJSMTcxGzAZBgNVBAsTEkpPUkdFIENPUk9OQSBEVVJBTjCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAnnOz6hCym1vtbA6N3LPB2/dGJweT9E8EqFXdHbnq2CPaNQUKyNMLDfBJCI7KdgNE67rJPNiGgaa/o9iyXzDBqCqEK67uadESL9wSJJ4+Ljk+9iXrQvQE0qsqKp05WWbZ6UBIMpGud0jaGnDonXbX6GrF/qmjb08HBFVqIhaJf/cCAwEAAaMdMBswDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADALBgNVHQ8EBAMCBsAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAA1WDsvSBX2+YxURH8qcR9ddBs71hTXMl4qp/N3S8/L9ISfcMTfDqRrLHpeC03Ru/w2LSXKywcIQHtbUpBDMdzfseS7xJn7QBswH2wRLmjgi7MUFSHQW9mNDGbpBPm6MNe8dbhvK0KWfz7FWgAcCzUj4xKIBLyxIDdlG21GBBYjXpWGGuf30NUSXvx8c7PeCqtZPI25H80BxSMI5Z85BoLtgh7dw87q7bQT5gs59JFearYaJPyXn6yCWHY4uJM25FSeo2OpIl78Ase7uwDuADYvyDzpmD5HFWo9KszehlWTnm4D8OmLsTFkyHzGyIi/PfSbf1mFdKSIBtB53uAyJ4pU=" subTotal="869.39" TipoCambio="1.00" Moneda="Peso Mexicano" total="828.82" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" metodoDePago="NO IDENTIFICADO" LugarExpedicion="FRANCISCO I. MADERO 2017 , NUEVA, 21100, MEXICALI, MEXICALI, BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO">
    <cfdi:Emisor rfc="CODJ7002145Q3" nombre="JORGE CORONA DURAN">
        <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="FRANCISCO I. MADERO" noExterior="2017" colonia="NUEVA" localidad="MEXICALI" municipio="MEXICALI" estado="BAJA CALIFORNIA" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="21100"/>
        <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="PERSONA FISICA CON ACTIVIDAD EMPRESARIAL Y PROFESIONAL"/>
    </cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor rfc="VME990127Q70" nombre="VSF MEXICO S.A. DE C.V., SOFOM, E.N.R.&#xA;">
        <cfdi:Domicilio calle="AVE SANTA FE&#xA;" noExterior="495" colonia="MANZANA B LOTE B1 20&#xA; COL. CRUZ MANCA&#xA;" localidad="MEXICO" municipio="CUAJIMALPA" estado="DISTRITO FEDERAL" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="05349"/>
    </cfdi:Receptor>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="No aplica" noIdentificacion="RECU" descripcion="RECUPERACION" valorUnitario="869.39" importe="869.39"/>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosRetenidos="179.67" totalImpuestosTrasladados="139.10">
        <cfdi:Retenciones>
            <cfdi:Retencion impuesto="ISR" importe="86.94"/>
            <cfdi:Retencion impuesto="IVA" importe="92.73"/>
        </cfdi:Retenciones>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16.00" importe="139.10"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" selloCFD="abnLKgvWQ+pPBW1YSI/N941kf7eDOn8GBttp1/AJAdkQS6n60s37saV9ugTfOpYM4G+Q+4zr0jn0RQldamFyMDo/F3BfPg3R9yG8SD5A45i4Sh3CL/El2AHH/Zkyvft8b+BgFAMCoauvpi61BOCNK1EjEPcro0eZoy8ZRBfv+Xo=" FechaTimbrado="2015-03-04T14:48:50" UUID="07BEEF18-45AF-5F3B-BB44-C2758802ADCF" noCertificadoSAT="00001000000202864883" version="1.0" selloSAT="pnaIMS1fcN4BIkKmoibQQTYANHJeG+1uvwO32ZC4io0wM/INNnspsig9/R+GrCx+fHwCGmyISlU+WLgmww9G5IpB4YuNywJW1j0ggaFunW2hOyLfgmYC2IJeMPUCxrL8pd64NiyNMYzNb0zI/6miefmzgSnAAFZXAYB3YuAMoPo="/>
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

I am trying to validate the schema using the generated schema file but I am getting a false. Please see my vb.net code below:

```
 Protected Function XmlValidate(ByVal xmlFile As String, ByVal invoiceSchema As String, ByVal digitalSchema As String) As Boolean
            Try
                Library.Log("Xml validation began for voucher file " & XmlFile & " begins: ", LogType.INFOLOG, ImportType.VOU)
                Dim settings = New XmlReaderSettings()
                settings.Schemas.Add("", invoiceSchema)
                settings.Schemas.Add("", digitalSchema)
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
                AddHandler settings.ValidationEventHandler, New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf ValidationEventHandler)
                Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(XmlFile, Settings)
                While reader.Read()
                End While
                reader.Close()
                Library.Log("Voucher file validation completed for file " & XmlFile, LogType.INFOLOG, ImportType.ECOUNSEL_IMP)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Library.Log("Voucher Imported errored out (XMLValidate):" & ex.ToString(), LogType.ERRORLOG, ImportType.ECOUNSEL_IMP)
                _import = False
            End Try
            XmlValidate = _import
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Validation event hanlder for xml validation
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="sender"></param>
        ''' <param name="e"></param>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        Protected Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ValidationEventArgs)
            Try
                Select Case e.Severity
                    Case XmlSeverityType.Error
                        Dim err As String = e.Message.ToString()
                        Library.Log("Error occured while validating xml" & err, LogType.ERRORLOG, ImportType.ECOUNSEL_IMP)
                    Case XmlSeverityType.Warning
                        Dim err As String = e.Message.ToString()
                        Library.Log("Error occured while validating xml" & err, LogType.ERRORLOG, ImportType.ECOUNSEL_IMP)
                End Select
                _import = False
            Catch ex As Exception
                Library.Log("Voucher import errored out in ValidationEventHandler:" & ex.ToString(), LogType.ERRORLOG, ImportType.ECOUNSEL_IMP)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to compare a schema against a schema (read your posting), or a schema against the xml file?  The schema is either failing due to the namespaces or the additional schema checks at the url of the namespace.  You need to validate the xml using a check tool.  Easiest method is to use the check in you VS project.  Do following from menu : Project : Add New Item : XML File.  Then paste your xml into view.  Errors will be display in Error List just like any compiler error.

Comment: You should share the exception you are getting.  That should tell you why the validation is failing.